# convert varchar to date sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a day in `varchar` and month and year also in `varchar` they are separated how to convert it in `date` format in SQL server

Comment: show some sample input data

Comment: We can't see your data. Please provide some samples. This sounds like, however, you've made the mistake of storing your data as the wrong data type, and (unsurprisingly) its come to back to bite you. Alwats use the correct data type for your data. stores dates as a `date`, times as a `time`, date && times and `datetime2`, numerics as a `int`/`decimal`, etc, etc. `varchar` is not a "one size fits all` datatype. `sql_variant` almost fulfils that, but still, you should be using the proper data type when you can.

Comment: Concatenate and convert

Comment: You can also use `DATEFROMPARTS()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Year nvarchar(50) = '2018'
DECLARE @Month nvarchar(50) = '7'
DECLARE @Day nvarchar(50) = '3'

SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, @Month, @Day)
```

Answer (score 0):

use CONVERT() or CAST() to convert

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, year_column + month_column + '01') as DateTimeColumn
```

Comment: select cast(cast(p.Year*10000 + p.Month*100 + p.Day as varchar(255)) as date) FROM Personnel p
 SELECT CAST(CONCAT(CAST(p.Year AS VARCHAR(4)), '-',CAST( p.Month AS VARCHAR(2)), '-',CAST(p.Day  AS VARCHAR(2))) AS DATE) FROM Personnel p
 SELECT convert(date, CONVERT(nvarchar(10), Year) + '-' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10),  Month) + '-' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), Day)) as 'Date'  FROM Personnel;

Comment: @malaklaghoz please update your original question with the query